# How can I select the strength of my AES encryption i.e 128, 256, 512 etc.?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, symmetric-key

Below is an example of how I am encrypting text in java, although the encryption works. I can't seem to figure out how I can modify the level of encryption i.e 128, 256, 512 etc.

Code:

```
byte keySelectedByUser[] = selectedKey.getBytes();
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keySelectedByUser, "AES");

Cipher cipher;

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes());
```

How can I do this in java?

Comment: the x in AES-x is the key length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061658/how-to-switch-from-aes-256-to-aes-128 - PBE makes keys of different length from passwords

Answer (score 2):

Use `SecretKey`. For example:

```
final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
final SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("YourPreferredAlgorithm");
final SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(pass, salt, iterations, KEY_LENGTH));
```

Then use the `SecretKey` to obtain your `SecretKeySpec`:

```
final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer abit further i.e. pass, salt, iterations and factory. As I don't completely understand what you're referring to?

Comment: Iterations is the amount of times the password is hashed during the derivation of the (symmetric) key. A general rule of thumb is: more iterations = harder to bruteforce. The salt is a extra precaution to prevent bruteforce attacks: you need to know the salt and the password before you can check if your hash is valid. For more information, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html#PBEKeySpec(char[],%20byte[],%20int,%20int)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126061/pbekeyspec-what-do-the-iterationcount-and-keylength-parameters-influence).

Answer (score 1):

There is no AES-512. AES only supports key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bit. In Java you select the appropriate key size by passing in a key of that size: `byte[]` of length 16, 24 or 32.

If you have a password and you want to stretch a key from that, then you need to use a password-based key derivation function such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2. Be sure to adjust the iterations or the cost factor according to your needs: as high as possible without too much inconvenience for the user.